# why $H(x) = - \int_{x^2}^{0} \sqrt tdt + \int_{0}^{ 2-x^2} \sqrt t dt ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem taken from *Apostol calculas* books Volume $2$ page no: $361$

**Question** : If $Q = [ -1, 1] \times [0,2]$, Evaluate the double integral $\int \int _{Q} \sqrt {| y- x^2 |} dx dy$ 
given that exist

**My attempt**:  I got  the  answer  but i didn't understand  the  given answer  below . My confusion marked in Red colour see  my doubt  given below

> [image]

we have $t= y- x^2$, suppose if $t=x^2$  , then $y= 2x^2$ and if $t= 2,$ then $y- x^2= 2$ , then $y=  2 + x^2$

Then  $H(x)  = - \int_{x^2}^{0} \sqrt tdt +  \int_{2x^2}^{ 2+x^2} \sqrt t dt$

**My doubt**  is why   $H(x)  = - \int_{x^2}^{0} \sqrt tdt +  \int_{0}^{ 2-x^2} \sqrt t dt ?$

Comment: I think they want you to understand more like $y=t+x^2$ which makes senses because the variable in  your integral is $y$. Since $y$ goes from $x^2$ to$2$, $t$ will go from $0$ to $2-x^2$.

Comment: It seems you may have just gotten the order the wrong way around. We wish to convert the limits for $y$ into limits for $t$, not vice versa. When $y = x^2$, $t =0$, giving the lower limit. And when $y = 2$, $t = 2 - x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $H(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}\,\text{d}y+\int_{x^2}^2\sqrt{y-x^2}\,\text{d}y$.

In this exercise, when integrating, you're doing it respect to $y$, so when changing variables, you should think that we want to transform $y$ into something else, in this case $t$. You start knowing $y$ and we want to know how $t$ works, so your information in the change of variables should be gotten from $y$, this is, when changing limits of integration and that kind of things you should ask yourself what happens to $y$ (since it's the variable you know a priori) and then how this transforms into $t$ (the variable you know little about and you want to use).

For the first integral, we set $t=x^2-y$ in $\displaystyle\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}\,\text{d}y$ and we ask ourselves what happens to $t$ (the variable we want to know about) when $y=0$ and $y=x^2$ (the variable we already had). When $y=0$ we have $t=x^2$; when $y=x^2$ we have $t=0$. Moreover, when we do $dy$ we get $dt=-dy\,$ ($x^2$ acts as a constant here). Then $\displaystyle\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}\,\text{d}y=-\int_{x^2}^0\sqrt{t}\,\text{d}t=\int_{0}^{x^2}\sqrt{t}\,\text{d}t$.

For the second integral, we set $t=y-x^2$ in $\displaystyle\int_{x^2}^2\sqrt{y-x^2}\,\text{d}y$ and we ask ourselves what happens to $t$ (the variable we want to know about) when $y=x^2$ and $y=2$ (the variable we already had). When $y=x^2$ we have $t=0$; when $y=2$ we have $t=2-x^2$. Moreover, when we do $dy$ we get $dt=dy\,$ ($-x^2$ acts as a constant here). Then $\displaystyle\int_{x^2}^0\sqrt{y-x^2}\,\text{d}y=\int_{0}^{2-x^2}\sqrt{t}\,\text{d}t$.